# JavaScript Array equals to string, how?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How following code works?

```
var result = ["test"] == "test";
console.log(result); // returns true
```

I have tested in chrome and ["string"] == "string"` returns true.

Comment: see what `["test"].toString()` results in ... then check out type coercion

Comment: In most of case, when doing == comparison in JS, JS implicitly converts arguments to string and then compares them, thus ["test"].toString() == "test"

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, It looked weird to me that this works :)

Comment: @HiteshBhayani use `===` to get what you expected (avoid type coercion).